# How to unset PATH?

Tags: php, windows, batch-file

I know it is possible to set **PATH** programmatically with using for example

```
SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.16\
```

But how can I unset **PATH** programmatically?

The reason why I want to unset **PATH** is that I could not rename my text file because it will show this error.

**The action cannot be completed because the file is open in php.exe**

Comment: You cannot unset a system environment variable. And why can't you rename your txtfile? Why are you even using the PATH environment variable?

Comment: I think the error is not connected to the PATH value.More probably  php.exe is running and hold the file.

Comment: @npocmaka,yes php.exe is holding the file,.I don't know why but i already closed my batch file.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to unset **PATH** in a command prompt window or in a batch file for everything started from within this command interpreter process after doing that.

The possible commands are `set PATH=` or `path ;` as explained in help of command `path` output in a command prompt window after entering `path /?` or `help path`.

But **PATH** is not unset for any process already running and for new process started not from within this command interpreter process.

To remove **PATH** is a good method for testing a batch file which should be executed by Windows task scheduler. If nothing in the batch file depends on **PATH**, the probability is high that it works also with Windows task scheduler running with a different account/credentials.

But in your case of being not able to rename a text file as being currently opened by php.exe, it is of no use to unset **PATH**. Terminate PHP process and rename the file, or restart Windows which results also in terminating PHP process and rename the file after Windows started again.

Answer (score 0):

You just set a new path

```
path c:\windows\system32;c:\windows;c:\windows\system32\wbem
```

which is system standard path.

You can use set to remove C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows from path.

```
`set path=%PATH:C:\Program Files\Debugging Tools for Windows=%`
```

watch out for trailing semi colons.

Though it's unlikely to help your specific problem.

The formatting has fucked up, make sure you put =% on the end of the line.